# Problemas com Numeração de Página com iText

Tags: java, itext

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou precisando criar relatórios com o iText. Tudo estava indo muito bem até a hora em que precisei numerar estes relatórios. Encontrei uma [resposta no post de outra pessoa no GUJ](http://www.guj.com.br/java/95922-imprimir-numero-de-paginas-no-itext), mas não deu muito certo.

Baseado neste tutorial (adequado ao meu contexto) eu consegui numerar apenas a última página de cada PDF. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como numerar todos? Melhor ainda se for no modelo "Página 1 de X".

Segue a Classe completa para auxiliar:

```
public class Relatorio extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    private Font titulos = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 20, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(73, 146, 255));
    private Font subtitulo = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 15, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(73, 146, 255));
    private Font labels = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD);
    private Font content = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL);
    private List lista;
    private String filepath;

    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter w, Document d) {
        PdfContentByte cb = w.getDirectContent();
        cb.saveState();
        try {
            String txt = "Página "+w.getPageNumber();
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

            float txtBase = d.top();
            float txtSize = bf.getWidthPoint(txt, 8);
            float adj = bf.getWidthPoint("0", 80);

            cb.beginText();
            cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 8);

            cb.setTextMatrix(d.right() - txtSize - adj, txtBase);
            cb.showText(txt);

            cb.endText();
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        cb.restoreState();
    }

    private void prepararPDF(String nome, int opcao) {
        Document doc = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        String username = new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName().toString(); // Nome do usuario logado
        String fileName = null;
        filepath = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop\\Relatórios Hydros\\" + nome + "\\";

        try {
            File diretorio = new File(filepath);
            if (!diretorio.exists()) {
                diretorio.mkdirs();
            }

            fileName = "TEMP_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd").format(new Date()).toString() + ".pdf";
            doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 40, 40);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath + fileName);
            PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fos);

            doc.open();

            switch (opcao) {
                case 1: relatorioReservatorios(doc); break;
                case 2: relatorioBombas(doc); break;
                case 3: relatorioPlacas(doc); break;
                case 4: relatorioPortas(doc); break;
                case 5: relatorioBombasXReservatorios(doc); break;
            } 

            onEndPage(w, doc);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (doc != null)
                doc.close();

            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                    adicionarMarcaDagua(filepath, fileName);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void adicionarMarcaDagua(String path, String name) {
        try {
            String filepath = path + name;
            String newfilepath = path + name.substring(5);

            PdfReader pdfr = new PdfReader(filepath);
            int paginas = pdfr.getNumberOfPages(); 

            PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfr, new FileOutputStream(newfilepath));

            int i = 0;
            Image watermark = Image.getInstance("C:\\Users\\Hugo\\Dropbox\\Programação\\Java\\Projetos\\Eduardo\\Hidros\\Workspace\\Hidros\\WebContent\\resources\\img\\watermark.png");

            watermark.setAbsolutePosition(50, 375);
            watermark.scaleAbsolute(500, 110);

            PdfContentByte pdfcb;
            while (i < paginas) {
                i++;
                pdfcb = stamp.getUnderContent(i);
                pdfcb.addImage(watermark);   
            }
            stamp.close();
            pdfr.close();

            excluirArquivo(filepath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void excluirArquivo(String path) {
        File f = new File(path);
        if (f.delete())
            System.out.println("Excluiu");
        else
            System.out.println("Não excluiu");
    }

    private void relatorioReservatorios(Document doc) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("RELATÓRIO DOS RESERVATÓRIOS - " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()) + "\n", titulos);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        p = new Paragraph("Quantidade: " + lista.size() + " unidades.", subtitulo);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        PdfPCell cell;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CAPACIDADE (Lts)", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TIPO", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OBSERVAÇÃO", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        Reservatorio r;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) { 
            r = (Reservatorio) lista.get(i); 

            // Nome do reservatório 
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r.getNomeReservatorio(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Capacidade do reservatório
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(r.getCapacidadeReservatorio()), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Tipo do reservatório
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r.getTipoReservatorio(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Observação do reservatório 
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r.getObsReservatorio(), content));
            table.addCell(cell); 
        }

        table.setWidths(new int[] { 80, 80, 80, 80 }); // Largura das colunas
        doc.add(table);
    }

    private void relatorioBombas(Document doc) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("RELATÓRIO DAS BOMBAS - " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()) + "\n", titulos);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        p = new Paragraph("Quantidade: " + lista.size() + " unidades.", subtitulo);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        PdfPCell cell;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("VOLTAGEM (V)", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("POTÊNCIA (W)", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OBSERVAÇÃO", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        Bomba b;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {  
            b = (Bomba) lista.get(i); 

            // Nome da Bomba 
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(b.getNomeBomba(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Voltagem da Bomba  
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(b.getVoltagemBomba()), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Potência da Bomba 
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(b.getPotenciaBomba()), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Observação da Bomba
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(b.getObsBomba(), content));
            table.addCell(cell); 
        }

        table.setWidths(new int[] { 80, 80, 80, 80 }); // Largura das colunas
        doc.add(table);
    }

    private void relatorioPlacas(Document doc) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("RELATÓRIO DAS PLACAS - " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()) + "\n", titulos);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        p = new Paragraph("Quantidade: " + lista.size() + " unidades.", subtitulo);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell cell;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("IP", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        Placa pl;
        Anchor anchor;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {  
            pl = (Placa) lista.get(i); 

            // Nome da Placa 
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(pl.getNomePlaca(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            anchor = new Anchor(String.valueOf(pl.getIpPlaca()));
            anchor.setReference("http://"+pl.getIpPlaca());

            // IP da Placa 
            cell = new PdfPCell(anchor);
            table.addCell(cell);
        }

        table.setWidths(new int[] { 80, 80 }); // Largura das colunas
        doc.add(table);
    }

    private void relatorioPortas(Document doc) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("RELATÓRIO DAS PORTAS - " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()) + "\n", titulos);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        p = new Paragraph("Quantidade: " + lista.size() + " unidades.", subtitulo);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        Porta po;
        Placa pl;
        Bomba b;
        Reservatorio r;

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            PdfPCell cell;

            po = (Porta) lista.get(i);
            pl = po.getPlaca();
            b = po.getBomba();
            r = po.getReservatorio();

            // Pular linha
            doc.add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            // Nome da Placa
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME DA PLACA", labels));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(pl.getNomePlaca(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // IP da Placa
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("IP DA PLACA", labels));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(pl.getIpPlaca()),
                    content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Número da Porta
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NÚMERO DA PORTA", labels));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(po.getNumeroPorta()),
                    content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Número da Porta
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TIPO DA PORTA", labels));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(po.getTipoPorta().getNomeTipoPorta(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Nome da Bomba
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME DA BOMBA A QUE ESTÁ VINCULADA", labels));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(b.getNomeBomba(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Nome da Bomba
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME DO RESERVATÓRIO A QUE ESTÁ VINCULADA", labels));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r.getNomeReservatorio(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            table.setWidths(new int[] { 250, 170 }); // Largura das colunas
            doc.add(table);
        }
    }

    private void relatorioBombasXReservatorios(Document doc) throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("RELATÓRIO DE\nBOMBAS X RESERVATÓRIOS - " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date()) + "\n", titulos);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        p = new Paragraph("Quantidade: " + lista.size() + " unidades.", subtitulo);
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.add(p);

        doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));

        Bomba_Reservatorio br;
        Bomba b;
        Reservatorio r;

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell cell;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME DA BOMBA", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("NOME DO RESERVATÓRIO", labels));
        table.addCell(cell);

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) { 
            br = (Bomba_Reservatorio) lista.get(i); 
            b = br.getBomba();
            r = br.getReservatorio();

            // Nome da Bomba 
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(b.getNomeBomba(), content));
            table.addCell(cell);

            // Nome da Bomba 
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r.getNomeReservatorio(), content));
            table.addCell(cell); 
        }

        table.setWidths(new int[] { 250, 170 }); // Largura das colunas
        doc.add(table);
    }

    public void gerarRelatorio(int op, List lista) throws IOException {
        this.lista = lista;

        switch (op) {
            case 1: prepararPDF("Reservatórios", op); break;
            case 2: prepararPDF("Bombas", op); break;
            case 3: prepararPDF("Placas", op); break;
            case 4: prepararPDF("Portas", op); break;
            case 5: prepararPDF("Bombas X Reservatórios", op); break;
        } 

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer " + filepath); 
    } 
}
```

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está utilizando de forma errada a classe `PdfPageEventHelper`. No trecho

```
PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fos);

doc.open();

switch (opcao) {
    case 1: relatorioReservatorios(doc); break;
    case 2: relatorioBombas(doc); break;
    case 3: relatorioPlacas(doc); break;
    case 4: relatorioPortas(doc); break;
    case 5: relatorioBombasXReservatorios(doc); break;
} 

onEndPage(w, doc);
```

você está chamando o método `onEndPage(w, doc)` depois de gerar o relatório pelo `switch`.Ou seja, ele adicionará o conteúdo deste método somente na página atual do documento, neste caso, a última.
Este método, assim como o método `onStartPage`, não devem ser chamados de modo avulso, pois eles são métodos que são automaticamente chamados pelos eventos de `endPage` e `startPage`. O que você deve fazer é mudar este trecho para:

```
PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fos);

w.setPageEvent( this );

doc.open();

switch (opcao) {
    case 1: relatorioReservatorios(doc); break;
    case 2: relatorioBombas(doc); break;
    case 3: relatorioPlacas(doc); break;
    case 4: relatorioPortas(doc); break;
    case 5: relatorioBombasXReservatorios(doc); break;
}
```

onde `this` é a classe que extende o `PdfPageEventHelper`. No seu caso, é a própria classe `Relatorio`.
Desse modo, você estará atribuindo um "listener" aos eventos de `endPage` e `startPage` deste documento e avisando ao iText que, ao chegar ao fim de uma página, o método `onEndPage(w, doc)` deve ser chamado.
É possível numerar no formato "Página 1 de X", mas o único modo que posso pensar é gerar duas vezes o documento. Na primeira vez, pode ser através de um arquivo temporário, então pode ser utilizado o iText mesmo para verificar quantas páginas este documento possui. Desse modo, ao gerar pela segunda vez, você terá o número de páginas que este documento possuirá.
Considere também separar a classe `PdfPageEventHelper` e o restante do relatório, o código fica mais organizado e fácil de entender.